# How to count how many times appears a number in a column of an HTML table

Tags: html, bash

I have an HTML report with a table and I need to count how many times a number appears in a specific column. This should be made in bash (on Fedora).
Let's take the next example. I need to count how many times number 3 and number 2 appear (on column 3) in all table:
`<tr>`
`<td>test11</td>`
`<td>test12</td>`
`<td>3</td>`
`<td>test14</td>`
`</tr>`
`<tr>`
`<td>test11</td>`
`<td>test12</td>`
`<td>3</td>`
`<td>test14</td>`
`</tr>`
`<tr>`
`<td>test11</td>`
`<td>test12</td>`
`<td>2</td>`
`<td>test14</td>`
`</tr>`

Comment: Do you mean a count of the 2s and a count of the 3s? Or the two together?

Comment: In my table on column 3 I have numbers from 1 to 4. In the final I need this: 1 - x times, 2 - y times, 3 - t times, 4 - z times

Comment: Take a look at [tag:xmllint].

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/questions/266641/is-there-a-native-tool-for-parsing-xml-files-available-on-redhat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using gnu awk you can do:

```
awk -v RS='</tr>' -v F='<td>' '$4~/>3</{a++; next} $4~/>2</{b++; next}
     END{printf "3-count=%d, 2-count=%d\n", a, b}' file
3-count=2, 2-count=1
```

Comment: This works, but if I have 3 on the first column this is counted and the number 2 from the third column (which I need to count) is not counted.

Comment: This works and it returns what I need. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd better need a search form for another query. What if you need to know other number or info than '3'? So I've made a search function to count an exact word on the page.

**HTML**

```
<table border width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>test11</td>
        <td>test12</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>test14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>test11</td>
        <td>test12</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>test14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>test11</td>
        <td>test12</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>test14</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<hr />
<form action="" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="text" class="text-input" id="filter" value="" /> <span id="filter-count"></span>

    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#filter").keyup(function () {

        // Retrieve the input field text and reset the count to zero
        var filter = $(this).val(),
            count = 0;

        // Loop through the comment list
        $("table td").each(function () {

            // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
            if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
                $(this).fadeOut();

                // Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
            } else {
                $(this).show();
                count++;
            }
        });

        // Update the count
        var numberItems = count;
        $("#filter-count").text("Number of results = " + count);
    });
});
```

DEMO here : http://jsfiddle.net/nobuts/0empj2e6/2/

Comment: I don't think this qualifies as a Bash solution (-:

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: Bash is a popular Unix command shell.  The OP requested a solution which works in this environment.  His system might not have a browser installed at all.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that keyword. Only think of a html document. Thank you for the explanation. :D

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to extract information from HTML is with something like [`xpath`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/xpath.1p.html).

```
xpath '//tr/td[3]/text()' file.html |
sort | uniq | sort -rn
```

If you don't have `xpath`, you could do it easily with something like

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import lxml.html
import sys
from collections import defaultdict

d=defaultdict(int)

for f in sys.argv[1:]:
    root = lxml.html.parse(f)
    for item in root.xpath('//tr/td[3]/text()'):
        d[item] += 1
for item in d:
    print "%s occured %i times" % (item, d[item])
```

Comment: Added a quick and dirty Python solution as well.  Like the link will tell you, `xpath` ships with the `XML::Path` library for Perl.  With Python >= 2.4 (I think) comparable functionality is already included out of the box.

Comment: Oops, I was a bit *too* quick -- [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) is not part of the standard library, but well worth installing.

Comment: This is what I want. Great solution. This should be run on many computers and the lxml module should be installed on all of them, but it's ok. Thanks a lot.

Comment: but xpath cannot be used without python?

Comment: There are many implementations, the `xpath` command I linked to is Perl and you can easily get XPath libraries for C and Java etc.  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) has a list of implementations (scroll down) but it's necessarily incomplete and probably badly out of date.

Answer (score 0):

Quick-n-Dirty:

```
cat tab.html | tr -d '\n' | sed 's|</\?tr>|\n|g' | sed 's|</\?td>|\t|g' | tr -s '[:space:]' | cut -f4 | uniq -c
```

Answer (score 0):

Using perl - Mojo::DOM parser:

```
perl -Mojo -0777 -nlE '$c{$_->find("td")->[2]->text}++ for x($_)->find("tr")->each}{say "$_: $c{$_}" for keys %c' << EOF
<tr> <td>test11</td> <td>test12</td> <td>3</td> <td>test14</td> </tr>
<tr> <td>test21</td> <td>test22</td> <td>3</td> <td>test24</td> </tr>
<tr> <td>3</td>      <td>2</td>      <td>2</td> <td>3</td> </tr>
EOF
```

prints:

```
3: 2
2: 1
```

But for this you need to have installed [Mojolicious](https://metacpan.org/release/Mojolicious).